# rel="preload" affecting Javascript window.onload?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onload, preload, srcset

I noticed that if I `srcset` preload images (for a sibling page) via `rel="preload"`, Javascript's `window.onload` is firing*after **all** the images have loaded, not just the actually visible images on the current page. Is this intentional or is playing Chrome tricks on me? (Also, weirdly, Chrome does not preload the `srcset` images when idle, but before idling).

JS:

```
window.onload = () => {
  console.log("page loaded")
};
```

HTML:

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="image-500px.jpg" imagesrcset=" image-500px.jpg 500w, image-500px.jpg 800w, image-500px.jpg 1000w">
```

I'm using the network tab in the Chrome developer tools.

https://web.dev/preload-responsive-images/

–> **Update in the comments.**

Comment: Quote https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content, _“[…] lets you declare fetch requests in the HTML's <head>, specifying resources that your page will need very soon, which you want to start loading early in the page lifecycle, before browsers' main rendering machinery kicks in.”_ - so bascially, you are prioritising those images, as if they were important resources for the _current_ page. Since you just indicated that they were that important, I am not too surprised, that firing of the load event waits for those now.

Comment: (I did not check against the specification, whether that is supposed to be the correct behavior, but it appears quite logical to me on first thought.)

Comment: _“not just the actually visible images on the current page”_ - preloading has nothing to do with whether you use the same image on the same page later on, the browser does not do any checks for that. You said, preload this with high priority, so the browser preloads this, with high priority.

Comment: Then I mistook `prefetch` for `preload`. Thanks for the clarification. I guess if `prefetch` is not working with `srcset` responsive images, its use for image-heavy sites is almost obsolete. ‍♂️  I'll look into using the `media query` attribute on the `prefetch <link>`.

Comment: Update for anyone trying to use the `media attribute` on the `<link>` tag when using `prefetch`: it doesn't work – it's prefetching anyways, even if the media query is not met. Like `media="(max-width: 320px)"`

Comment: Yeah, browsers do that, so that there isn’t a massive “lag” when the user switches screensizes, or turns their mobile/tablet from protrait to landscape.

Comment: Makes sense but also renders image preloading via prefetch kind of obsolete then. Maybe browsers could allow media queries on the prefetch tag only on initial page load and not when the user switches screen sizes.